# Loop Multi Function In Thread

Tags: c#, function, loops

I want to have a loop that automatically executes functions when the form starts, I set the property to start from `void Form1_Load()`
from start point to end point and automatically return to where it started and continue like that indefinitely.

1 > 2
2 > 1

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{Start();}

private void Start()
{
  P0_();
  Thread.Sleep(10000);
  P_1();
}
private void P0_()
{
  //MyCode
}
private void P1_()
{
 //MyCode
}
```

Comment: *"I want to have a loop"*. And yet I see no evidence of a loop in your code, so that's a fail. If you want to have a loop, you should probably have a loop.

Comment: I mean a loop that runs strings, it's like timer tick

Comment: i want to have loop in function Start();
from P0 to P1 and From P1 to P0

Comment: Poorly asked question. First try to solve the task yourself and then show the result and say what you tried to do

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this without loops or threads by making use of a `Timer` component.

The below form uses a `Timer` with an interval to trigger the `Timer_Tick` event handler and the enum tracks state.

If you have `async` operations to do, you can just make `Timer_Tick` an `async void` method.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private enum TickType
    {
        Tick,
        Tock
    }

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer _timer = new();
    TickType _tickType = TickType.Tick;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_tickType == TickType.Tock)
            _tickType = TickType.Tick;
        else
            _tickType = TickType.Tock;

        label1.Text = _tickType.ToString();
    }
}
```

Another way would be to use an infinite loop with `await Task.Delay()` inside a "fire and forget" `async void` method, but I would recommend the first method to keep things simple.